# Spring boot using Webflux & Kotlin: CRUD operation from inside a subscribed Mono is failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, subscribe

I'm in the process of testing how to query data from the "jsonplaceholder" API and save the received data to a local Postgresql database. When I make a call from Postman, the received data is returned correctly by "jsonplaceholder", but weirdly nothing is stored in the database.
Maybe I'm just missing something in my code (see below), I don't know!
This is a Spring Boot application with Webflux and Kotlin and Postgres'SQL as local database.
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    /* The config file: WebfluxConfig.kt*/
    package com.example.monoSubscribe.config

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
    import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.CorsRegistry
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFlux
    class WebfluxConfig: WebFluxConfigurer {

    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("api/**")
    }
    override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: 
    ServerCodecConfigurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1)
    }
    }
```

```
    /* The model: Post.kt */
    package com.example.monoSubscribe.model

    data class Post(
    val userId: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val body: String
    )
```

```
    /* The Repository: JsonholderRepo.kt */
    package com.example.monoSubscribe.repo

    import com.example.monoSubscribe.model.Post
    import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository

    interface JsonholderRepo: ReactiveCrudRepository<Post, Long> {
    }
```

```
    /* The service: AppService.kt */
    package com.example.monoSubscribe.service

    import com.example.monoSubscribe.model.Post
       import com.example.monoSubscribe.repo.JsonholderRepo
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
    import org.springframework.web.util.UriBuilder
    import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

    @Service
    class AppService( private val jsonholderRepo : JsonholderRepo ) {

    fun createPost(postReq: Post) : Mono<Post> {
        return jsonholderRepo.save(
                Post(
                    userId = postReq.userId,
                    id = postReq.id,
                    title = postReq.title,
                    body = postReq.body
                )
            )
    }

    /** Call remote API (json placeholder) */
    fun fetchPosts(): Flux<Post> = 
    fetch("/posts").bodyToFlux(Post::class.java)
    fun fetch(path: String): WebClient.ResponseSpec {
        val baseURL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
        val client = WebClient.create(baseURL)
        return client.get().uri{
                builder: UriBuilder ->
            builder.path(path)
                .build()
        }.retrieve()
    }
    }
```

```
    //The controller: AppController.kt
    package com.example.monoSubscribe.controller

    import com.example.monoSubscribe.model.Post
    import com.example.monoSubscribe.service.AppService
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
    import reactor.kotlin.core.publisher.toMono


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    class AppController(private val appService: AppService) {


    @PostMapping("/posts")
    fun createPost(@RequestBody postReq: Post): Mono<Post> {
        return appService.createPost(postReq)
    }

    /** Call remote API - Json placeholder  */
    @GetMapping("/jsonplaceholder")
    fun getData(): Mono<ResponseEntity<List<Post>>> {
        val ret =  appService.fetchPosts()
            .take(3)
            .collectList()
            .map { body -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(body) }
            .toMono()
        ret.log().subscribe(
            {
                val x:List<Post> = it.body as List<Post>
                for (t in x){
                    print(t)
                    appService.createPost(t)
                }
            },null,
            { }
        )
        return ret
    }

    }
```

```
    /* The property file: application.yaml */
    spring:
      r2dbc:
        url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/
        username: postgres
        password: "*********"
      jpa:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            generate_statistics: true
    server:
      error:
        include-message:
    logging:
      file:
        name: src/main/kotlin/de/cops/webfluxPostgresql/logging/aam.log
```

```
    /* The build.gradle*/
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

    plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    }

    group = "com.example"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
    validation:2.7.5")
    }

      tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Comment: The mono tag is for something else. Please use the java tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way how you're trying to save posts in the database.

At the moment is not saved because this part of the code doesn't have time to execute. `subscribe` doesn't mean that the main thread will complete after the execution of these lines.

```
       ret.log().subscribe(
            {
                val x:List<Post> = it.body as List<Post>
                for (t in x){
                    print(t)
                    appService.createPost(t)
                }
            },null,
            { }
        )
```

In your case saving is running on a separate thread which doesn't block the main thread. The main thread completes before save operations took place. That's why the database is empty.

Saving posts operations should be a part of the reactive stream that you already have. If you put it before mapping to `ResponseEntity` you'll omit additional mapping from the response entity to post again.

Something like that should work.

```kotlin
        return appService.fetchPosts()
            .take(3)
            .flatMap { appService.createPost(it) }
            .collectList()
            .map { body -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(body) }
            .toMono()
```

Comment: Please use edit the post and add your current implementation at the end.